# TeamCity Tests tab doesn't show up in TeamCity 7.0

Tags: xcode, teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I just set up a new TeamCity 7.0 server that should be doing the exact same work as my 6.5.2 server.  I use the TeamCity Adapter from https://gist.github.com/994882 to notify TeamCity of test results.

The build logs on each server both show the tests passing, my the 7.0 server doesn't show the tests tab.  I don't remember doing anything special when the 6.5.2 server was setup.

[image: Missing Tests tab in TeamCity 7.0]

What do I have to do to get the tests tab to show up?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm seeing the same issue

Comment: No I never did put more time into trying to solve this issue.